# Unable to boot ArchLinux from LiveUSB

Tags: arch-linux, boot, windows, live-usb, bootable

I'm currently using Windows 7 on an AMD-A4-4000 APU - and I'm completely new to Linux. I made a LiveUSB of ArchLinux using Universal USB Writer. Now when I tried to boot from the USB Device - I got to a DOS-like screen - where, as far as I could make out the booting process was unfolding (probably).

Now, here they started showing me errors like :

Boot from /dev/sdc : No medium found

And, in the end they just kept on showing the following error (something like this):

[rootfs]* : File on USB Device 'descriptors' not found

So, I just rebooted the machine on default configurations.

Can anyone help me deal with this issue ?

Comment: Try creating the USB with LILI USB (Linux Live USB creator).

Comment: Ok, Let me try that

Comment: I tried creating the USB with LILI USB (Linux Live USB creator) and booting it from the USB again - but I'm still facing exactly the same problem as I have described above.

Comment: Can you boot or have a linux distro already installed? If you do you can `dd if=Path_to_your_arch_iso of=/dev/your_usb_device`. Be carefull if your USB has partitions or has data you don't want to lose, dd will wipe your partitions and copy the ISO to the USB including the MBR.

Comment: @YOMismo I got Ubuntu 11.10 up and running from a LiveUSB. Now, could you explain how I can go about executing the script you just gave me ?

Comment: It is not a script is a command. Just start ubuntu from the live CD, open an xterm and introduce the command I posted above. You will have to substitute "Path_to_your_arch_iso" to the full path and name of the arch's iso that you have downloaded, and "your_usb_device" by the name of the USB where you want to create arch's live CD (something like sdb, sdc). Be carefull since you already have a USB (the ubuntu's one) in the system be sure not overwrite that one and choose the one that is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, you can try to make a USB with [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/).

Please be sure to select the right setting between BIOS/UEFI (MBR supports everything normally).

If these errors keeps coming, try to re-download the ISO and re-try to burn it into you USB stick.

I hope it will help.